# Array resampling with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2000 x 200 hdf array from a 2000 run Monte Carlo. The data are the times in minutes before and after a certain event. For the first 50 or so rows, before the event is triggered, the time is negative, then when the event occurs, the time crosses zero and thereafter increases until the end of the simulation.  The data has no header, nor date column. This was how the data was given to me. I have loaded the data and extracted the time rows centered on a few minutes before and after the trigger event. I am now trying to use the Pandas resample function on this data subset to obtain a 1 second frequency data set for statistical analysis. I cant find any examples to help me up-sample a data array in the format in which this data was received. Perhaps I could add a date column to the array, or resample each column separately, but I wonder if anyone knows of a simpler faster way? Thanks and best regards!

Comment: There is a section of the documents specifically for [Upsampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#upsampling), but without actual data or any rules on how you want to fill the upsampling, it's far too broad of a question to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I created a small example (10 x 8) of the Monte Carlo data before, and after resampling. The array data is in units of minutes.

Comment: This is the ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  
-100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0 
-100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0 
   0.4     0.5     0.7     0.3     0.7     0.1     0.1 
   2.4     4.0     2.3     1.0     4.0     2.2     2.1 
   6.1     5.4     6.1     6.0     9.2     9.9     9.0 
  15.4    15.0    15.0    17.8    18.0    14.0    18.1 
  26.0    28.2    26.0    26.4    28.0    26.1    25.7 
  39.5    36.0    38.7    39.0    35.8    36.3    35.0 
  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...

Comment: This is the Monte Carlo data                          
 ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   
-100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0 
-100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0  -100.0 
   0.4     0.5     0.7     0.3     0.7     0.1     0.1 
   2.4     4.0     2.3     1.0     4.0     2.2     2.1

Comment: 6.1     5.4     6.1     6.0     9.2     9.9     9.0 
  15.4    15.0    15.0    17.8    18.0    14.0    18.1 
  26.0    28.2    26.0    26.4    28.0    26.1    25.7 
  39.5    36.0    38.7    39.0    35.8    36.3    35.0 
 ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...

Comment: This is the resampled data                          
  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ... 
  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 
  0.1   1.4   0.5   0.1   1.1   0.4   0.5   1.0   0.1   0.5 
  1.1   2.1   1.1   0.3   2.1   1.1   1.1   2.1   0.6   1.1 
  2.1   3.1   2.1   1.1   3.1   2.1   2.1   3.1   1.1   2.1

Comment: 3.1   4.1   3.1   2.1   4.1   3.1   3.1   4.1   2.1   3.1 
  4.1   5.1   4.1   3.1   5.1   4.1   4.1   5.1   3.1   4.1 
  5.1   6.1   5.1   4.1   6.1   5.1   5.1   6.1   4.1   5.1 
  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...